# Nothing happens when I try and use this plugin (InlineDisqussions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have followed the instructions [here](http://tsi.github.io/inlineDisqussions/) but I'm not seeing any sign of InlineDisqussions working on my web page, apart from the files showing up in the html in Firebug. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="inlineDisqussions.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, saepe, libero, alias accusamus minus voluptas quae veniam nesciunt laudantium unde magni dolor omnis voluptatem ab a id eum explicabo veritatis!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, culpa, ducimus, libero, animi odio mollitia a impedit dolore dolorum pariatur nisi earum dolorem ipsam ut quam nam alias sint rerum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, voluptatem.</p>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="inlineDisqussions.js"></script>
    <script>
        disqus_shortname = 'myshortname';
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("p").inlineDisqussions();
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have included both inlineDisqussions.css and inlineDisqussions.js in my folder.

This is not the first time I have tried to use a plugin and nothing happens, so perhaps I don't understand something basic. However, I have used other plugins without a problem.

How do I get it working please?

Comment: Is the browser console showing any error?

Comment: Also make sure you have your disqus name correct(case sensitive) and that jquery.js is also in the same folder as this file. Anyway +1 for nicely asked first question \o/ not everyone does it right :D

Comment: Thanks for the replies and up votes! I figured it out and provided my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I wasn't seeing the inlineDisqussion speech bubbles next to my paragraphs because I had disabled horizontal scrolling on my page by setting overflow-x to hidden, and the speech bubbles were positioned off the page.

Thanks for the replies!